# AspectJ module dependency with Maven - How get working the Inter-type declarations methods of a dependency module

Tags: java, maven, aop, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

**This is my situation:**

[image: Workspace-my-project-aj-dependency]

I have a maven project `my-project-aj-dependency` composed by two jar modules:

- `my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithAJ` (where I have an [Inter-type declaration](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-interType.html), see the `ahah()` method below inside the aspect `AppWithAj_Ahah.aj`)
- `my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithoutAJ`

***My problem is that I would like to use some declared method defined in the aspect of the first module inside the second module, but probably I missed something.***

**My poms configuration is the following:**

Maven project pom (`my-project-aj-dependency`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <name>MyProjectAjDependency</name>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependency</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <!-- <module>TestMaven-ejb</module> -->
        <module>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithAJ</module>
        <module>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithoutAJ</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithAj</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithoutAj</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Maven module 1 pom (`my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithAJ`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependency</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithAJ</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithAJ</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
         <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
         <version>1.8.9</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <source>${java-version}</source>
               <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>install</id>
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>sources</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--
                    Have to use version 1.2 since version 1.3 does not appear to work
                    with ITDs
                -->
            <version>1.2</version>
            <dependencies>
               <!--
                        You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see
                        MNG-2972)
                    -->
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                  <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                  <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>compile</goal>
                     <goal>test-compile</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <outxml>true</outxml>
               <source>${java-version}</source>
               <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Maven module 2 pom (`my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithoutAJ`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependency</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
   <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithoutAJ</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithoutAJ</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
         <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithAj</artifactId>
         <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <source>${java-version}</source>
               <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>install</id>
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>sources</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--
                    Have to use version 1.2 since version 1.3 does not appear to work
                    with ITDs
                -->
            <version>1.2</version>
            <dependencies>
               <!--
                        You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see
                        MNG-2972)
                    -->
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                  <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                  <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>compile</goal>
                     <goal>test-compile</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <outxml>true</outxml>
               <source>${java-version}</source>
               <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Where `AppWithAj.java` is:

```
package org.my.project.aj.dependencyJarWithAJ;

public class AppWithAj {
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

and `AppWithAj_Ahah.aj` is:

```
package org.my.project.aj.dependencyJarWithAJ;

public aspect AppWithAj_Ahah {
    public String AppWithAj.ahah(){
        return "Ahahahah!";
    }
}
```

and finally `App.java` is:

```
package org.my.project.aj.dependencyJarWithoutAJ;
import org.my.project.aj.dependencyJarWithAJ.AppWithAj;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World! " + new AppWithAj().ahah());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is way too complicated:

- The AspectJ (AJ) module needs the AJ Maven plugin and a dependency on *aspectjrt*. So far, so good.
- But the declared aspect only affects a class within its own module, extending it via ITD. So there is no need to use the AJ compiler on the pure Java module which only calls a method from the AJ module. It is irrelevant that the called method was created by ITD, to the other module it looks just like normal Java.
- Consequently, all the non-AJ module needs is a normal dependency on the AJ module because it uses one of its classes. The AJ runtime dependency is transitive and should be used automatically.

**Update:**

You asked for POMs, here they are.

**Root POM:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependency</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyProjectAjDependency</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.source-target.version>1.7</java.source-target.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithAj</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
                <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithoutAj</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.source-target.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.source-target.version}</target>
                        <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                        <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--<showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>-->
                        <source>${java.source-target.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.source-target.version}</target>
                        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                        <complianceLevel>${java.source-target.version}</complianceLevel>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                        <!--<verbose>true</verbose>-->
                        <!--<warn>constructorName,packageDefaultMethod,deprecation,maskedCatchBlocks,unusedLocals,unusedArguments,unusedImport</warn>-->
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                            <phase>process-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithAJ</module>
        <module>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithoutAJ</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

**Module with AspectJ:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependency</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithAJ</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Plain Java module:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependency</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithoutAJ</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.my.project.aj.dependencyJarWithoutAJ.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithAj</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Please note: I have added the Exec Maven plugin just for demo purposes, so you can do something like this:

```
mvn clean install
mvn -pl my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithoutAJ exec:java
```

Then you should see something like this on the console:

```
(...)
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ my-project-aj-dependencyJarWithoutAJ ---
Hello World! Ahahahah!
```

Remove Exec Maven from both the root and the plain Java POMs in order to get even shorter POMs.

Comment: Ok, could you please paste here the simplest poms (like in my answer below) so I can accept your answer? 
You can even copy paste my poms and delete the unuseless parts, then I'll delete my answer
:D Thank you!

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, it really simpler like this.
However I have still a question/problem...
If I run from eclipse the org.my.project.aj.dependencyJarWithoutAJ.App it works fine but it still mark a sort of warning near the use of ahah() method inside the org.my.project.aj.dependencyJarWithoutAJ.App main.
Near my answer I pasted a snapshot. Let me know about it.
Thanks again and again!

Comment: Do I have to add the aspectj-maven-plugin plugin without the aspectj dependency to avoid this kind of warning inside the nonAj proj?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this pom configuration:

Project pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <name>abc</name>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
   <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <modules>
      <module>abc1</module>
      <module>abc2</module>
   </modules>
   <properties>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
      <aspectj.version>1.8.9</aspectj.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
            <artifactId>abc1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
            <artifactId>abc2</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <build>
      <pluginManagement>
         <plugins />
      </pluginManagement>
   </build>
</project>
```

Pom of the first module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
      <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
   <artifactId>abc1</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>abc1</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
         <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
         <version>1.8.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <source>${java-version}</source>
               <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>install</id>
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>sources</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--
                    Have to use version 1.2 since version 1.3 does not appear to work
                    with ITDs
                -->
            <version>1.2</version>
            <dependencies>
               <!--
                        You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see
                        MNG-2972)
                    -->
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                  <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                  <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>compile</goal>
                     <goal>test-compile</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <outxml>true</outxml>
               <source>${java-version}</source>
               <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Pom of the second module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
      <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
   <artifactId>abc2</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>abc2</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.madx</groupId>
         <artifactId>abc1</artifactId>
         <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <source>${java-version}</source>
               <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>install</id>
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>sources</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!--
                        Have to use version 1.2 since version 1.3 does not appear to work
                        with ITDs
                    -->
            <version>1.2</version>
            <dependencies>
               <!--
                            You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see
                            MNG-2972)
                        -->
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                  <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                  <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                  <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>compile</goal>
                     <goal>test-compile</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
               <outxml>true</outxml>
               <source>${java-version}</source>
               <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Here I show it working: [AspectJ module dependency with Maven](https://youtu.be/GxGcOaJFCQs)

**Edit:**
It seems that if the nonAj project doesn't have a AspectJ nature it warns you near the .aj defined methods (although it works fine if you simply launch it, for eclipse it is not an error, by the way this not allow you to use the autocomplete ad fills the code with wanings...). This is the snapshot:
[image: Warning if the other has not a Aj nature]